# Catching native C++ exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, exception

I have some native C++ class libraries that I have wrapped up in C++ .NET which I then call from C# (three layers!).

I can throw exceptions from C++ .NET and happily catch them in C#. The trouble is that the only way I can catch my native C++ exceptions is by catching System.Exception, which is fine but in the conversion from std::exception to System.Exception I lose the vast majority of the information about the error (for example the error message!). I can catch the native exception in the C++ .NET layer and rethrow as a .NET exception but this is an intrusive solution that requires me to place try-catch blocks (to catch the native exceptions and rethrow) around every C++ .NET method call.

Is there an alternative solution to doing this or am I just going to have to get my hands dirty ...

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0624f3b3-5244-4cb8-be9c-29d464975d20/

Comment: I don';t think there's an alternative.. So either live with it and look at the call stack which gives the line in the native code where the exception was thrown, or use the wrapper approach with a custom exception (which makes more sense to me: why should C# have to know about std::exception?) btw you should probably be catching ExternalException or SEHException, not Exception

Comment: how are you catching the exceptions in C#? I can't catch them. My C++ DLL was created with MinGW though, I don't know it that would be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to get your hands dirty, but you can reduce the work a lot by creating a preprocessor macro to encapsulate all the repeated catch logic.

I am assuming you will want to catch several different types of exception, e.g. MFC CException, std::exception, as well as SEH exceptions.

You ***might*** also want to write your wrapper functions to return HRESULTS and use SetErrorInfo (i.e. convert to COM error codes and error information) - you may decide this gives a cleaner interface to .Net which can convert this nicely to .Net exceptions. This would avoid the need for a C++.Net layer and allow you to use P/Invoke, as well as making it callable from VBA.

Or you might not... just pointing out the option!

Comment: or if you're using c++11 you can skip on the macro and add a wrapper function that can take lamdas