# How do I catch a custom exception generated in a c++ dll on c#?

Tags: c#, c++, exception, try-catch

I'm creating a C++ DLL to be used in C#. This DLL throws exceptions whenever anything is wrong and the idea is to handle these in the C# code.

I created a new exception class in C++ inheriting from `std::runtime_error` because I not only need the `what` but also a numeric ID:

```
class insight_exception: public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    explicit insight_exception(const int id, const std::string message):
    std::runtime_error(message), id{id}
    {}

    virtual ~insight_exception() noexcept {}

    const int id;
};
```

Whenever something goes wrong in the C++ code I do this:

```
throw insight_exception(103, "size Pointer is NULL");
```

I have a little example in C# to "exercise" the DLL, just to test it before sending it to our C# developer, and when I execute the little C# program I can verify that the DLL is throwing the exceptions because I'm getting this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'insight_exception'
```

My problem is that I don't know any C# and I don't really know to "import" the `insight_exception` class into C# so I can catch it.

Solutions like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315051/using-a-class-defined-in-a-c-dll-in-c-sharp-code) don't help because they assume you can use the class by using a function like this:

```
insight_exception* create_insight_exception()
{
    return new insight_exception();
}
```

And I can't do that because I need something like this in C#

```
try
{
}
catch (insight_exception e)
{
}
```

So I can't create the class like:

```
IntPtr insight_exception = create_insight_exception();
```

One important thing to know is that I'm creating the DLL on Linux by cross-compiling using MinGW, so I can't do `#include <Windows.h>` or any other windows-related includes or imports when creating the DLL. I don't really use Windows but only for my little test C# code.

---

EDIT:

Thanks to a comment, I looked into the following questions:

[C# not catching unhandled exceptions from unmanaged C++ dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223470/c-sharp-not-catching-unhandled-exceptions-from-unmanaged-c-dll)

This one looks promising but the problem is that the answer suggest a compilation done in Windows. I tried to add the `/EHa` compilation flag equivalent in GCC (-funwind-tables) but that doesn't help. I still can't catch the exception using `catch (SEHException ex)` nor `catch (Exception ex)` in the C# code.

---

[Can you catch a native exception in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150544/can-you-catch-a-native-exception-in-c-sharp-code)

Suggests using `Win32Exception` but that doesn't work either. I can't catch the exception with `catch (Win32Exception ex)` in the C# code.

Comment: `catch(SEHException ex)`?

Comment: @Charlieface and then what? That doesn't seem to do anything. Also, the code doesn't go to the catch, it just crashes.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [C# not catching unhandled exceptions from unmanaged C++ dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4223470), [Can you catch a native exception in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/150544), [Catching native C++ exceptions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11948651), [How to handle exceptions from native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40468923)

Comment: Can you catch any Exception `catch(Exception ex)`

Comment: @Charlieface no, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I initially missed the point about the cross compiling... Most probably: **NO**, you cannot catch this exceptions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5108118/1810087

Comment: And just `catch {  }`?

Comment: @Charlieface no, I still can't with `catch {}`. I think I will have to use return codes instead. I just checked the link `user1810087` mentioned and I see the problem.

Comment: @user1810087 ok, I see. I think I will have to use return codes instead.

Comment: Exceptions are not covered by the standard and depend on the implementation. Different vendors use different implementation which will not match. So `catch { }` should not work, and if it does by some luck, don't depend on it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/491120/1810087

Comment: @user1810087 ok, that makes sense. It really seems not possible because of the way exceptions work. Well, I will then use a simple return code.

Comment: Another option than the error codes would be using MSVC for your C++ part and C++/CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56965916/1810087

Comment: C++ stack unwinding is an arcane art full of platform specific hacks. IMHO, write a C++ stub to catch the exception and return some kind of success / failure object.

Comment: @user1810087 though that is a good solution, it is not possible because I would have to create a "3rd piece of code" which is the CLI-wrapper and nobody will like that, especially because the exceptions are not required and I can solve easily with a return value and not introducing more source files and code.